# Digest Value ,trust store, Certificate validation mode

Tags: wcf, interop

I am connecting to an external java webservice using WCF. I have no control over the service. 
The supporting tokens are 2 x509's and one username token, sign and encrypt only the body. I am able to generate a 100% compliant request as per vendor soap request sample.

WCFClient uses a custombinding to generate the outgoing request. I am getting a problem with Digest Value in the response. How do I even check, verify this?. 
The server log says the following : 
Signer status: 'Extracted the certificate chain from the BinarySecurityToken having format x509'
 Reject set: Hash values do not match.
Hash values do not match: 'l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE=', which is the  Digest value in the Signature.

```
 <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
      <o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-1" />
      </o:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
    <e:CipherData>
      <e:CipherValue>REMOVED=</e:CipherValue>
    </e:CipherData>
    <e:ReferenceList>
      <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
    </e:ReferenceList>
  </e:EncryptedKey>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="#_1">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>gCwFapZ3D/vUXsvAShTQwNWJoA23ad54NRmUWXR7IBFbsr75HBdZUG5lO1Af+ncShzwJA2a6jJXJmw/1gKswyAP9QuZsa9D+6fGh8jwcVqjm5v/Sh9rgQxWjL6U1kkovP0IAqEjafRu6YgmauFVCHUrJ2QfIN96WYTPnYm9Puvs=</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <o:SecurityTokenReference>
        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-2" />
      </o:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
```

As per my knowledge I am not doing anything special 
Custom binding does all of this

Would it be an issue with trust stores. Working soap UI sample has a truststore cacerts with a pwd changeit. I think this ships with javakeytool. 
I am using the following custom binding and chain trust

```
      AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement secBE = AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement();
                secBE.AllowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply = true;
                secBE.DefaultAlgorithmSuite = SecurityAlgorithmSuite.TripleDesRsa15;
                secBE.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;
                X509SecurityTokenParameters x509ProtectionParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
                x509ProtectionParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
                secBE.InitiatorTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
                secBE.RecipientTokenParameters = x509ProtectionParameters;
                secBE.MessageProtectionOrder = MessageProtectionOrder.SignBeforeEncrypt;
                secBE.RequireSignatureConfirmation = false;
                secBE.IncludeTimestamp = false;
                CustomTextMessageBindingElement enc = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement(Encoding.UTF8.ToString(), "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11);
                HttpsTransportBindingElement b = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
                b.RequireClientCertificate = true;
                CustomBinding be = new CustomBinding();
                be.Elements.Add(secBE);
                be.Elements.Add(enc);
                be.Elements.Add(b);
                   -----------------------------
 proxy.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "Usercert");
            proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "ServerCert");
            proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
            proxy.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.ChainTrust;
```

Updated to show working both the working request and the faulty one
Both are the same as per my knowledge. One difference is the order
Working one has BST, UST, BST
Mine has BST, BST, UST. 
Working Soap UI Request

```
      <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soapenv:Header><wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
       <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" wsu:Id="6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868206455">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
       <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868206454" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
       <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
       <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
       <wsse:Reference URI="#6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868206455" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
       </wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo>
       <xenc:CipherData>
       <xenc:CipherValue>e5nL8OsjXRBtVrkV6eb4W5KhgOas2UL3C26BmcAArBZNk+yBVQoCIRTBMXYomvLeHFB/oNO3RqXEd8NTrSTnC8ydH/BEf9vKSGqsyQzaEkk4oV93fgWtMgE4DErUS/8oBS2DcgvtJle1tpoNR7FNp7iBif0idmGyL6L2lBT9HmM=</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData>
       <xenc:ReferenceList>
       <xenc:DataReference URI="#ED-4"/></xenc:ReferenceList></xenc:EncryptedKey>
       <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-3">
<wsse:Username>USERID</wsse:Username>
       <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PWD</wsse:Password>
       <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Vjjuy4+O3TwT7BmMACfLQA==</wsse:Nonce>
       <wsu:Created>2013-08-01T19:53:40.446Z</wsu:Created></wsse:UsernameToken>
       <wsse:BinarySecurityToken EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="X509-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868202121">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</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
       <ds:Signature Id="SIG-2" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       <ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
       <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="mhs soapenv" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:CanonicalizationMethod>
       <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#id-1">
       <ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#">
       <ec:InclusiveNamespaces PrefixList="mhs" xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms>
       <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue>FchA3vEpfP7i3adziwVpYnrI/BQ=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo>
       <ds:SignatureValue>ZnEgibHIj1B+Gk+m8THvgNownzH8eCfymugLIHM+EyZsPz+xyOAd+IR43LAo/LcuAVZK8lBrtFKc
    DJO2zETYXv9gXnQP4Z8kAirkOtWuE6nPPwooSBlGXRr/j2zOp6ekdCoyqI7Hlhljh0NVaIbwzAsS
    yfrsYGw0I0zJzfI3Hkc=</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="KI-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868203372">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1" wsu:Id="STR-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868203413" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
    <wsse:Reference URI="#X509-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868202121" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509PKIPathv1"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature></wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="id-1" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
       <xenc:EncryptedData Id="ED-4" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
       <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/><ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
       <wsse:SecurityTokenReference wsse11:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-soap-message-security-1.1#EncryptedKey" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsse11="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
       <wsse:Reference URI="#EK-6BB387229F4FD6E3FC13753868206454"/></wsse:SecurityTokenReference></ds:KeyInfo>
      <xenc:CipherData><xenc:CipherValue>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</xenc:CipherValue></xenc:CipherData>
      </xenc:EncryptedData>
      </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope
```

Below is the request which my custombinding generates. It fails at the Signature-Digest Value

```
  <s:Envelope xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
      <s:Header>
        <ActivityId CorrelationId="2297e645-5077-443d-a7d2-d9af74ddb07e" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/09/ServiceModel/Diagnostics">00000000-0000-0000-2400-0080020000f7</ActivityId>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
          <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-5" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
          <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-4" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">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</o:BinarySecurityToken>
          <o:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
            <o:Username>USERID</o:Username>
            <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PWD</o:Password>
            <o:Nonce>19sRmzQElHKqxL6ICMzpJf7NOU8=</o:Nonce>
            <o:Created>2013-07-31T09:24:00.933Z</o:Created>
          </o:UsernameToken>
          <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
            <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
              <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-4" />
              </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
            <e:CipherData>
              <e:CipherValue>XQQjLvSY5VJ4BYkDxdsIUYYFRz+eleKaiU5bSFpUMblIm7ssKXOLJJsLBbNHREycIV8u5LR9ZixI7nI5BeacKYT+nlEikPREgUwEbvsGMb6LxkquUsIDhicpY5lKMhijbYtrE8O0Ee1TX3kT6hRb6QnvWZSGjnDhfLZvu3SO9cY=</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
            <e:ReferenceList>
              <e:DataReference URI="#_2" />
            </e:ReferenceList>
          </e:EncryptedKey>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
              <Reference URI="#_1">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>gCwFapZ3D/vUXsvAShTQwNWJoA23ad54NRmUWXR7IBFbsr75HBdZUG5lO1Af+ncShzwJA2a6jJXJmw/1gKswyAP9QuZsa9D+6fGh8jwcVqjm5v/Sh9rgQxWjL6U1kkovP0IAqEjafRu6YgmauFVCHUrJ2QfIN96WYTPnYm9Puvs=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-63c0b13f-8368-4bc9-a493-b362c67ac14b-5" />
              </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </o:Security>
      </s:Header>
      <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
          <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc" />
          <e:CipherData>
            <e:CipherValue>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</e:CipherValue>
          </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: please publish a working soap request and the failing one (the one you generate) so we can compare. also just to make sure - the server rejects the message, it is not your client that rejects the response right?

Comment: yes that is correct. External java service rejects the message. Throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Messages look very similar, a little disappointing that the server rejects WCF. You should be prepared that this can take some time to troubleshoot. I would try debug this with the following different approaches:

1. Based on the error message I assume the challenge is in the digest calculation. See how the soap UI has this element "". This element is an instruction to the signature signer/validator. Maybe the server hard codes this value into its signer in some way so the fact that WCF does not have it affects the digest. WCF cannot be configured to have this (usually it is not a problem not to have it). See if there is any configuration in SOAPUI where you can also not use it and see if it still works.
2. replace SignBeforeEncrypt with EncryptBeforeSign
3. setup a WCF service for the same WCF client and see if it works (though it probably will, so this is a long shot).
4. Try to contact the service from clients in other platforms, see how the server reacts.
5. Try to remove complexity from the service - e.g. remove the encryption and just use signature. See if that works. This can help pinpoint the problem.
6. The brute force way would be to find the service code that calculate the xml canonicalization and the digest and debug it viz-a-viz to the .Net code. But at that stage you would probably seek to bypass the problem in some other way.

Comment: Hi Yaron, Not sure if it would help. I was able to simulate the same error: Hash values do not match in soapUI. When I set the outgoing WSconfiguration in Soap UI, this is the order of the working request. Signature, Username, Encryption (or) Username, Signature and encryption. Error occurs when I have Encryption,signature, usernametoken. So this tells me that I need to use SignBeforeEncrypt.

Comment: Hi Yaron, This is just another observation. My digest value always has the same l6kqP048t5INzJT3W8gxVSXplaE value. The working one on SOAP Ui differs for each request.In this request it is FchA3vEpfP7i3adziwVpYnrI/BQ=. And different for each request. Does this mean, I am not signing it correctly

Comment: the last observation is interesting. try to change again to the order of signature and encryption in soapui. does the digest still change each request? If the digest is changing I beleive it means that you are signing after encryption so the dynamic encryption id causes the digest to change. if you sign before encryption then you just sign the raw soap body and unless you have put there something dynamic it should be fixed. so I would double click on the order issue again. In addition in my suggestion #1 the xml was ommited. Instead of empty "" it should be the element "ec:InclusiveNamespaces"